# How to train annotations tools

Tags: gene, sequence-annotation

I would like to train Augustus, SNAP and GlimmerHMM. I found protein sequences in GenBank and orthodb.org. Furthermore, I found HMM files on busco-data.ezlab.org.

```
$ wget -c https://busco-data.ezlab.org/v5/data/lineages/viridiplantae_odb10.2020-09-10.tar.gz
$ wget -c https://v100.orthodb.org/download/odb10_plants_fasta.tar.gz
```

Are there any instructions on how to train those annotations tools?

Thank you in advance